# Magento get compare URL by product id’s

Tags: php, magento

I am looking for the URL which automatically compare the product after passing ids or SKU to the url

Currently in magento after clicked on compare button the compare popup URL is like below:

**yoursite/index.php/catalog/product_compare/index/**

So I required the URL which automatically compares the products after passing the params to it?

Is there any way present by default in magento or I have to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally able to get the URL

**yoursite/index.php/catalog/product_compare/index/items/1,2**

here 1 and 2 are ids of products which you want to compare.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, first you need to load product like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(id);
```

or

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadBySku(sku);
```

Now use:

```
Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)
```

to get compare url of product.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also ,

helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>">__('Add to Compare') ?>